# UITableView duplicate cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am making `UITableView` with many cells.

Than in code, i am adding custom view in cells, and after 10 rows my custom `UIView` duplicates.

See more in the screenshots.

[image: bag]

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    EFMyTrainingPreviewTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"previewCell"];

     "SOME CODE"

    return cell;
    }

    -(void)makeCompleteButtonForWorkOut:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    EFMyTrainingPreviewTableViewCell *cell = (EFMyTrainingPreviewTableViewCell *)[_tableviewMyTraining cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [_tableviewMyTraining scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];

  "SOME CODE"

        [touchViewCompleteApproach addSubview:view];

    }
    [cell addSubview:touchViewCompleteApproach];

}
```

Comment: Hello!  you are using Storyboard?

Comment: yeah, i using Storyboard

Comment: it will be helpful to let know what do you do in the *some code* part as a summary. are you adding the custom view to an existing cell in the table when some button is pressed ? if so make sure you remove the added subview after you're done else when tableview reuse that cell, the added subview will remain for other cells which you dont intend to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` will help you because when you scroll table view it refreshes the cells, and uses custom cells with views and buttons you wish.
It's simple and your code will look nice.
But beware of using `addSubview` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach in your case is to add a subview inside the method cellForRowAtIndexPath. Using the indexPath as the source for getting a reusable cell can lead to reusability buttons.

Wish it helps!

Comment: Can I add in function cellForRowAtIndexPath subspecies using another function without duplicates ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question